# GLSL/OpenGL - Single color instead of the texture

Tags: opengl, colors, textures, glsl, shader

I recently started learning GLSL, and now i have a problem with texturing. I've read all topics about it, i've found the same problem solid color problem, but there was a different problem that caused that. So, i have a simple quadrilateral(ground) and i simply want to render a grass texture on it. Shaders:

Fragment:

```
#version 330

uniform sampler2D color_texture;

in vec4 color;
out vec2 texCoord0;

void main() 
{
gl_FragColor = color+texture(color_texture,texCoord0.st);
}
```

Vertex:

```
#version 330
uniform mat4 projection_matrix;
uniform mat4 modelview_matrix;

in vec3 a_Vertex;
in vec3 a_Color;
in vec2 a_texCoord0;

out vec4 color;
out vec2 texCoord0;

void main() 
{            
texCoord0 = a_texCoord0;
gl_Position = (projection_matrix * modelview_matrix) * vec4(a_Vertex, 1.0);
color = vec4(a_Color,0.3);
}
```

My texture and primitive coords:

```
static GLint m_primcoords[12]=
{0,0,0, 
0,0,100,
100,0,100, 
100,0,0};
static GLfloat m_texcoords[8]=
{0.0f,0.0f,
0.0f,1.0f,
1.0f,1.0f,
1.0f,0.0f};
```

Buffers:

```
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,vertexcBuffer);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,sizeof(GLint)*12,m_primcoords,GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,colorBuffer);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,sizeof(GLfloat)*12,m_colcoords,GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,textureBuffer);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,sizeof(GLfloat)*8,m_texcoords,GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

and my rendering method:

```
GLfloat modelviewMatrix[16];
GLfloat projectionMatrix[16];

glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
glLoadIdentity();

cameraMove();

GLuint texturegrass = ploadtexture("grass.BMP");
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texturegrass);

glGetFloatv(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX,modelviewMatrix);
glGetFloatv(GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX,projectionMatrix);

shaderProgram->sendUniform4x4("modelview_matrix",modelviewMatrix);
shaderProgram->sendUniform4x4("projection_matrix",projectionMatrix);

glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);

glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
shaderProgram->sendUniform("color_texture",0);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,colorBuffer);
glVertexAttribPointer((GLint)1,3,GL_FLOAT,GL_FALSE,0,0);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,textureBuffer);
glVertexAttribPointer((GLint)2,2,GL_FLOAT,GL_FALSE,0,(GLvoid*)m_texcoords);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,vertexcBuffer);
glVertexAttribPointer((GLint)0,3,GL_INT,GL_FALSE,0,0);

glDrawArrays(GL_QUADS,0,12);
```

So, it looks like the code only reads 4 pixels from my texture(corners) and the output color will be `outColor = ctopleft+ctopright+cbotleft+cbotright` like this. 
I send more code if you want, but i think the problem lies behind these lines.
I tried different coordinates, ordering, everything. I also read almost all topics about problems like this. Im using the beginning ogl game programming 2nd ed., but dont have cd, so i cant check if I'm coding well, cuz only parts of codes are in the book.

Comment: Have you tried rendering what the texture coordinates look like?

Comment: You're binding your texture before you set the "active" texture unit. If you use multiple texture units in your software, then this might be to blame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of problems with your code.

1. In the fragment shader, you have declared texCoord0 as `out`, it should be `in` in the fragment shader and `out` in the vertex shader, since it is passed from one to the other.
2. You are binding your texture *before* you set the "active" texture unit. It defaults to GL_TEXTURE0, but this is still bad practice.

Comment: i changed them, now in the fragment shader the texCoord0 is "in" as it should be and now it all works. I also activate the texture unit before I bind it.